# Angular2:ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' and Angular2:ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispose' of null

Tags: json, rest, angular2-services

I am new to angular2, my target is to display the Json data which is returned from rest service, in my template, below is the Json data which is coming from rest service.

{"wellList":[{"country":"IDN","well":"Test","wellbore":"N","company":"Test","active":"N"},{"country":"IDN","well":"Test","wellbore":"N","company":"Test","active":"Y"},{"country":"IDN","well":"Test","wellbore":"N","company":"Test","active":"Y"},{"country":"IDN","well":"Test","wellbore":"N","company":"Test","active":"Y"},{"country":"IDN","well":"Test","wellbore":"N","company":"Test","active":"Y"}]}

The below is the code which i have written in my template:

```
 <ul>
 <li *ngFor="let well of wells | async">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Active</th>
        <th scope="col">Company</th>
        <th scope="col">Country</th>
        <th scope="col">Well</th>
        <th scope="col">Wellbore Indicator</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{{well.active}}</td>  
        <td>{{well.company}}</td>    
        <td>{{well.country}}</td>
        <td>{{well.well}}</td>
        <td>{{well.wellbore}}</td>  
      </tr>
      </table>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

But, no luck it is not working, giving the below two errors:

ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
    at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.es5.js:2610)
    at AsyncPipe.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js.AsyncPipe._selectStrategy (common.es5.js:2755)
    at AsyncPipe.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js.AsyncPipe._subscribe (common.es5.js:2741)
    at AsyncPipe.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js.AsyncPipe

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispose' of null
    at AsyncPipe.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js.AsyncPipe._dispose (common.es5.js:2761)
    at AsyncPipe.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js.AsyncPipe.transform (common.es5.js:2725)

Can anyone help me how to get rid of this

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { User } from '../user/user';
import {  Observable  } from 'rxjs/Rx';  
@Component({
  selector: 'app-well',
  templateUrl: './well.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./well.component.css'],
  providers:[UserService]
})
export class WellComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Wells';
  wells: User[];  
  errorMessage: string;
  constructor(private userService:UserService) {
    this.wells = [];  

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    let self = this;  
    self.userService.getWells().subscribe(response => this.wells = response, error => this.errorMessage = < any > error); 
  }

}
```

**Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response  } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable,Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';  
import { User } from '../user/user';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  //private jsonFileURL: string='/assets/wells.json';

  constructor(private  http:Http) { }
  getWells(): Observable < User[] > {  
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/auth/testuser1/pass',{headers:this.getHeaders()}).map((response: Response) => {  
        return <User[] > response.json();  
    }).catch(this.handleError);  
}  
//    
private handleError(errorResponse: Response) {  
    console.log(errorResponse.statusText);  
    return Observable.throw(errorResponse.json().error || "Server error");  
}  
private getHeaders(){
    // I included these headers because otherwise FireFox
    // will request text/html instead of application/json
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    return headers;
  }

}
```

Comment: can you give me your Component Code, just only template, i don't know your mistake where they are. =)

Comment: I have added my component and service there, please have a look

Answer (score 2):

ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe', i think you must check are you already include Asynce Pipe into the app.module.ts???. because this error is notice they don't have them.And this ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispose' of null at , is log after they can't run the 'AsyncPipe'. Hope this can help you fixed

Comment: I have removed the 'AsyncPipe', those two errors are gone but i got this below error

Comment: ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Comment: I have added the below line the error has gone and the data has displayed correctly thanks for the help.

Comment: Your extractData (and possibly also your HTTP API) is returning an object {} - ngFor requires an array [] to iterate.

Change your service/API to produce an array, or transform the object in your component.

Comment: Yes i have changed it and the error has gone Thank you.

Comment: can you tell me please which library should i add to have the Asynce pipe in app.module.ts ? i'm fascing the same error .

Answer (score -1):

asycnPipe is only deal with null, EventEmitter, promise and Observable, the `wells` is an object(JSON object). 
[enter link description here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts)

Comment: asycnPipe is only deal with null, undefined, promise and Observable,  not has EventEmitter, I'm so sorry